# How does tensorflow compute the gradient of `.linalg.eigh`?

Tags: tensorflow

Specifically, I am a bit confused about what happens when there are eigenvalues with >1 multiplicity.  In general, the Jacobian of the eigenvalues of a matrix with respect to its entries [is not defined](http://janmagnus.nl/papers/JRM011.pdf) (see section II) if the eigenvalues have multiplicity >1.  However, `tensorflow.linalg.eigh` doesn't seem to care about this, and happily returns a gradient whether there are multiple eigenvalues or not:

```
>>> sess.run(mat)
array([[1.50776616, 0.33370629, 0.37226308],
       [0.33370629, 1.21931333, 0.24465303],
       [0.37226308, 0.24465303, 1.27292051]])
>>> eigs, eigvs = tf.linalg.eigh(mat)
>>> sess.run(eigs)
array([1., 1., 2.])
>>> sess.run(tf.gradients(eigs,mat,tf.constant([1.,2,3], dtype=tf.float64)))
[array([[ 2.01553232,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.33482516,  1.99307962,  0.        ],
       [ 1.48905231, -0.01543994,  1.99138806]])]
```

Possibly it is the case that although the Jacobian is not generally defined, the total derivative is?  In any case, I'm having a difficult time imagining what to make of these gradients.  Can anyone shine some light on how the gradients are computed when there are eigenvalues with >1 multiplicity?